# RapidMiner - k-Medoids. Identify the medoid

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer

I am using Rapid Miner to see some results and performances for the k-Medoids algorithm. I was able to create the scheme and see the output but I would like to see inside each cluster created the central point (the medoid chosen) is there any way to do that?

Img1: Design [image]

Img2: Result [image]

Comment: K-medoids in rapidminer is a flawed implementation, if I recall correctly. I believe it doesn't actually implement k-medoids but a nonstandard variant of k-means. But it's a while since I looked at rapidminer for clustering, because I like ELKI much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Extract Cluster Prototypes` operator to create an example set corresponding to the cluster centroids. You can then use the `Append` operator to join it to the original data although there is a bit of work to do to get the example sets compatible.

Here's an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="k_medoids" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Clustering" width="90" x="179" y="136">
        <parameter key="k" value="3"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="313" y="136">
        <list key="function_descriptions">
          <parameter key="type" value="&quot;data&quot;"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="447" y="136">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="subset"/>
        <parameter key="attributes" value="label|id"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="extract_prototypes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Extract Cluster Prototypes" width="90" x="313" y="34"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes (2)" width="90" x="447" y="34">
        <list key="function_descriptions">
          <parameter key="type" value="&quot;centroid&quot;"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" breakpoints="before" class="append" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Append" width="90" x="581" y="85"/>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Clustering" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering" from_port="cluster model" to_op="Extract Cluster Prototypes" to_port="model"/>
      <connect from_op="Clustering" from_port="clustered set" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Extract Cluster Prototypes" from_port="example set" to_op="Generate Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

The `type` attribute can be used as the colour in a plot so you can see the centroids.